# aws-lib node was not generating result for host : "ecs.amazonaws.in"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, endpoint, aws-lib

I am using `aws-lib` for amazon procuct advertizing API.

My code is :

```
var aws = require("aws-lib");    
var prodAdvOptions = {
        host : "ecs.amazonaws.in",
        region : "IN",
        version : "2013-08-01",
        path : "/onca/xml"
    };

    prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey, yourAssociateTag,prodAdvOptions);

    prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", {
        SearchIndex : "Health & beauty",
        Keywords : "health",
        ResponseGroup : 'Images,ItemAttributes,Offers,Reviews'

    }, function(err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

        res.send({
            data : result
        });
    });
```

But result is {}.

If I am not passing `prodAdvOptions` means I am getting results.

```
prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey, yourAssociateTag);
```

Help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The host name I have given is wrong.

Instead of

> host : "ecs.amazonaws.in"

this one fixed the issue.

> host : "webservices.amazon.in"

And instead of `version` it should be `Version`